# If $u \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ vanishes at infinity then $Ku$ also vanishes at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given $X \subset \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ the subset of functions that vanish at infinity, i.e  $\ u : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} u(x) = 0$$
For $k \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $K :  X \to \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$(Ku)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} k_y(x) u(y) \ dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} k(x-y) u(y) \ dy$$ I want to show that $Ku$ also vanishes at infinity, so that $K$ maps from $X$ into $X$. I have already shown that $u$ is uniformaly continuous and that $K$ is linear and bounded, i.e $\|K \|_{op} \leq \|k \|_{L^{1}}$, but got stuck at that part.

Comment: This is a very good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0$, pick a $\varphi\in C_{00}$ such that $\|k-\varphi\|_{L^{1}}<\epsilon$, then
\begin{align*}
|(Ku)(x)|&=\left|\int k(z)u(x-z)dz\right|\\
&=\left|\int(k(z)-\varphi(z))u(x-z)dz+\int\varphi(z)u(x-z)dz\right|\\
&\leq\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\|k-\varphi\|_{L^{1}}+\left|\int\varphi(z)u(x-z)dz\right|.
\end{align*}
It suffices to control $\displaystyle\int\varphi(z)u(x-z)dz$.

Let $M>0$ be such that $\text{supp}(\varphi)\subseteq\{|x|\leq M\}$ and that $|u(w)|<\epsilon/(1+\|\varphi\|_{L^{1}})$ for all $|w|\geq M$. For all $|x|\geq 2M$ and $|z|\leq M$, then $|x-z|\geq|x|-|z|\geq 2M-M=M$, so $|u(x-z)|<\epsilon$, but then
\begin{align*}
\left|\int\varphi(z)u(x-z)dz\right|&=\left|\int_{|z|\leq M}\varphi(z)u(x-z)dz\right|\\
&\leq\int_{|z|\leq M}|\varphi(z)||u(x-z)|dz\\
&\leq\dfrac{\epsilon}{1+\|\varphi\|_{L^{1}}}\cdot\int_{|z|\leq M}|\varphi(z)|dz\\
&\leq\dfrac{\epsilon}{1+\|\varphi\|_{L^{1}}}\cdot\|\varphi\|_{L^{1}}\\
&<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
which is also small.

Comment: Nice! Thanks :)